# Datetime Conversion in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I receiving dates in the USA standard format `mm/dd/yy`.

I can upload to MySQL only in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd`.

How can you convert `mm/dd/yy` format to `yyyy-MM-dd` format in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* parse it and then format it. (`DateTime.ParseExact`, `DateTime.ToString`)

However, you *shouldn't* have to reformat for MySQL's benefit, and it suggests your database access is inappropriate:

- Your database column *should* be a DATETIME column or something similar, if you're storing dates in it
- Your database code *shouldn't* be including the value as a string at all. It should be passing it as a *parameter* with a `DateTime` value

So using parameterized SQL, you should just need to parse (e.g. using `DateTime.ParseExact`), then pass it up as a `DateTime`:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "mm/dd/yy",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
command.Parameters.Add("@Foo", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date;
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx ... please check here. you can convert the date format in C#

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQLs [STR_TO_DATE(str,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function. 
Or you can use [string formatting](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) in c#

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString);
string newDateString = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: I wouldn't use Convert.ToDateTime when we know the exact format. DateTime.ParseExact is more appropriate here IMO.

Comment: @Rahul: Neither part of this answer is ideal though. Using `Convert.ToDateTime` puts you at the mercy of the local system culture, and as I explain in my answer you shouldn't need to convert to a "MySQL-formatted" string at all.